# How locate xib of iPhone view (small size) in the middle of iPad detail view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a xib view file, created for iPhone, now I making iPad version. It is opens fine, but in the left top corner of the Detail View. I need to open it in the middle of the Detail View. I don't need to resize it, I just need to locate it in the middle of the Detail View. How can I do that? My code for open that xib file is...

```
NSArray *viewControllers;
StarsViewController *stars = [[StarsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StarsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, stars, nil];
                self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to place an iPhone-sized view controller as a component of an iPad app, I would suggest making the iPhone VC a child view controller and the full-screen iPad VC the parent view controller.

If you're using Storyboards and iOS 6 or later, container views and embed segues make this really easy. You just create a container view in your parent view controller, then control-drag from that container view onto the VC that you want to be the child, and set it up as an embed segue. At runtime, iOS does all the housekeeping required to set up the child view controller for you. It's great.